# Umbraco Database Connection Credentials

Tags: database, connection-string, umbraco

Where can I find the database credentials of my umbraco database?

In web.config there is just the following line:

```
<add name="umbracoDbDSN" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Umbraco.sdf;Flush Interval=1;" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
```

Which provides insufficient information...

Answer (score 2):

Your connection string clearly shows that you're using default SQL Server CE  database (`Umbraco.sdf`). You can find the `Umbraco.sdf` file in the `/App_Data` folder.

Depends on your requirement you can convert the SQL Server CE database to SQL Server Express or open up your solution in Webmatrix to see database tables.

You can find more information on conversion here https://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-7/using-umbraco-7/53818-Convert-Umbraco-SQL-CE-database-to-SQL-Express

To view database tables from webmatrix, you need to open up your solution and click the tab called databases.

umbracoUser is the table where you can find users.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using SQL Server CE and not a SQL Server instance

Comment: Exactly. Does that change the case?

Comment: I dont think that the sql ce installation does set up a password. That connection string is all umbraco needs. What is your problem/task exactly?

Comment: I'm trying to implement Google's sample code to store RefreshTokens into the database. In the sample code it is stored in a datastore. I'm implementing an IDatastore that communicates with the Umbraco Database. So I'm able to insert this data into the databank rather then a file. I was using sample code aswel for this implementation of the datastore which required me to fill out all the databank credentials. I decided to leave that approach and I'm just making a custom datastore using ApplicationContext.Current.DatabaseContext.Database. Which is working. Thanks for the help anyway.